# ANTLR4 - Memory leaks issue in parser

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, antlr4, swift5

I have been using the swift 5 version of ANTLR4 (4.8) in my iOS project.

```
        guard !expression.isEmpty else {
            return ""
        }
        let charStream = ANTLRInputStream(expression)
        let lexer = TemplateEngineLexer(charStream)
        let tokens = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
        let parser = try TemplateEngineParser(tokens)
        let tree = try parser.file()
```

The code is working fine but seems to leak memory. Is this a known issue? Since we are nearing a important release - we would want to fix this. Leak seems to be happening in the ANTLR code.

```
private func hash(_ config: ATNConfig) -> Int {
        if type == LookupDictionaryType.lookup {

            var hashCode: Int = 7
            hashCode = 31 * hashCode + config.state.stateNumber
            hashCode = 31 * hashCode + config.alt
            hashCode = 31 * hashCode + config.semanticContext.hashValue
            return hashCode

        } else {
            //Ordered
            return config.hashValue
        }
    }
```

I have attached the screenshot from Instruments.
[image: XCode Instruments - Memory leak]

Comment: I wonder how this `hash` function can leak memory. It doesn't allocate any and works only with Int values. In any case, you should file a bug report against the Switft target, in the [ANTLR4 code repository on Github](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4).

Comment: Thanks Mike. `config.semanticContext.hashValue` seems to be allocating memory for SemanticContext.Predicate

Comment: For now - I have replaced “config.semanticContext.hashValue” by a prime number to avoid the leak. Filed the bug report in ANTLR

Comment: A single number will not work. The hash is used to identify duplicate entities over multiple fields (object identity vs the standard object equality, which usually only compares the address of two objects). If you always return the same number I expect you will no longer be able to parse correctly. Also, the hash creation function is time critical and directly determines execution times, so be careful if you change something there.

Comment: Sure thanks. That was an initial attempt to see if it fixed the leak. I did replace it with a hasher based logic & now the leak is gone

Comment: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2821#issuecomment-629925928